# Click button twice crashes my Application

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibutton

Even with the search result I cannot find out how to proceed. I am new to xcode 7.

Got so far to create an application that consist out of one view, with one image that functions as a button and one label. The label is displaying text as a default.

I also created an array with several names. When the button is clicked a name is randomly selected from the array and displayed in the label.

All this is working fine but when the button is clicked again the app crashes...

The error code is the following

```
2016-01-28 20:25:07.705 Coffee Randomizer.temp_caseinsensitive_rename[3434:361389] -[UIButton setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa2cacd40b0
2016-01-28 20:25:07.719 Coffee Randomizer.temp_caseinsensitive_rename[3434:361389] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa2cacd40b0'
```

I guess I need to do something to refresh the label or something but can't seem to get a handle on it.

Update the OP with the code

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Coffee Randomizer
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

// MARK: add both the elements.
@IBOutlet weak var coffeeButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var coffeeLabel: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.        

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: Actions

// Not sure but this should be an array with possible names to select
var theCoffeeGuys: [String] = ["User1", "User2", "User3"]

@IBAction func setLabel(sender: UIButton) {
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(theCoffeeGuys.count)))
    coffeeLabel.text = theCoffeeGuys[randomIndex];
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where you've set the target of the button and the function to handle the button press?

Comment: My psychic powers tell me you have memory management issues.  You need to post your code.

Answer (score 1):

`'-[UIButton setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

You are attempting to send the `setText:` message to an instance of `UIButton`. There are several `UIView` subclasses which have a `text` property and will respond to `setText:` (`UILabel` for example) but `UIButton` is not one of them.

Unfortunately *why* you are sending this message to a button instead of whatever view you intended remains a mystery until you show your implementation.

Comment: As I am knew to this code I am learning on the go, but what I don't understand is why it works the first time, but exactly the same thing crashes on the second click. Should simply do the same thing, update the label again with a new randomly selected value.